# Swift - Delete value from model in realm

Tags: ios, button, swift3, realm

I'm trying to delete an object from my `realm` with `swift3`. When the user logs in with google, the userinfos are stored in realm db. Now I want to delete the user, when I click a button.

Here is my unfinished code:

```
@IBAction func deleteUser(_ sender: Any) {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    let userObject = realm.objects(userInfos.self).filter("id == 0").first
    realm.delete(userObject)
    try! realm.write

    print("deleted")
    print(userObject)
}
```

The code above is not working. What is wrong?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
if let userObject = realm.objects(userInfos.self).filter("id == 0").first {
    print("User is existed, it's being deleted.")
    try! realm.write {
         realm.delete(userObject)
    }
    print("Deleted.")
}
else{
    print("User is not found.")
}
```